# Problem in displaying yen symbol

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, localization

I am working on a sample application in this application I am displaying “Yen symbol”. But the displayed yen symbol is different from the standard yen symbol. The standard yen symbol contains:  Y with 2 horizontal lines at bottom. In my application the displayed yen symbol contains: Y with only one horizontal line at the bottom.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How a character is shown depends on the used font.

I think Windows used the Tahoma font by default in Windows XP.  And indeed, the Yen sign contains a single horizontal line in that font.

In Windows 7, it seems the Segoe UI font is used, which uses two horizontal lines in the Yen sign.

Use the CHARMAP application to check how the Yen sign looks in the different fonts, and change the font to that font in your window.

Answer (score 0):

definitely the problem related to fonts
Check which font you are using , if you are using MS Sans Serif than change it to tohoma or times new roman.